# Error in strcpy return not responding window

Tags: c, strcpy

this code is a headstart to make a simple dictionary. im trying to insert the word and the meaning into array. what seems the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

main(){
    char alp, *a[5][1], item[100],item2[150];
    for (int i =1;i <=5 ; i++){
        printf("\n\nEnter item [%d][%d]:",i,0);
        scanf("%s",&item);
        printf("Enter item meaning [%d][%d]:",i,0);
        scanf("%s",&item2);
        strcpy(a[i][0],item); //program stops here
        strcpy(a[i][1],item2);
        printf("word %s \nmeaning: %s",a[i][0],a[i][1]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Q: "What is `a[i][0]`?" A: "It is a pointer." Q: "Where does it point to?" A: "hmmmmmmmmmmm"

Comment: `scanf("%s",&item);` and `scanf("%s",&item2);` invoke *undefined behavior* by passing pointer to objects having wrong types: `%s` calls for `char*`, but what is passed are `char (*)[100]`.

Comment: Using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration `a[i][0]` and `[a][i][1]` also invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: What are you asking? You haven't said what the problem is. (The title "Error in strcpy return not responding window" might be an attempt to describe the problem, but I can't figure out just what it means.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define N   5

int main( void )
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
{
    char a[N][2][150], item[150], item2[150];
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^

    for ( int i = 0; i < N ; i++ )
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    {
        printf( "\n\nEnter item [%d][%d]: ", i, 0 );
        scanf( "%s", item );
                     ^^^^
        printf( "Enter item meaning [%d][%d]: ", i, 1 );
        scanf( "%s", item2 );
                     ^^^^^
        strcpy( a[i][0], item );
        strcpy( a[i][1], item2 );

        printf("word %s \nmeaning: %s\n", a[i][0], a[i][1] );
    }
}
```

This declaration

```
char *a[5][1];
```

declares a multidimensional array of pointers. You need to reserve memory where to copy strings.

And indices of arrays start from 0.

Comment: so ,did i just make mistake on the declaration of the char a[N][2][150], item[150], item2[150]; ? wew . thankyou this helps alot!

Comment: @Adam_Code I underlined statements that are wrong in your code. For example  you must to access elements of the array starting from 0. So for example the loop is also wrong.

Comment: thank you. the underline helps a lot for my understanding using the array.

Answer (score 1):

Your loop should be as follows:

```
for (int i =1;i <5 ; i++){
```

Notice the **<** rather than **<=**. If you declare an array of size 5, the last element is at index 4.

Also, initialize a as `a[5][2][100]` and not `*a[5][1]`

Comment: Not `a[5][1]` but `a[5][1][100]` or something. Passing `char` to `strcpy()` is bad.

Comment: so what's the proper way to passing a string into an array? @MikeCAT

Comment: @MikeCAT And not a[5][1][100] but a[5][2][150] :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't initialized the values in the `a` array, so you can't use them. When you call `strcpy`, you pass it the value of `a[0][0]` as the address to copy data into -- but it has no particular values yet because you've not set it to any value. So you're asking `strcpy` to copy the string to no place in particular.

You must assign a variable a value before you attempt to use its value. You must make a pointer point to something before you try to use the pointer's value as if it pointed to something.

You could do this:

```
a[i][0] = strdup (item);
```

The `strdup` function allocates memory and copies a string into that memory, returning a pointer to it. After this, `a[i][0]` will point to that newly-allocated memory that contains a copy of the string.

If your platform doesn't provide `strdup`, you can easily code it:

```
char *strdup (const char * i)
{
    char *j = malloc (strlen(i) + 1);
    if (j == NULL)
        return NULL;

    strcpy (j, i);
    return j;
}
```

You also access the array past the end. Your array has only five objects with indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4. So using an index of 5 is also illegal.

Lastly, in your `scanf` calls, you pass the address of your arrays of characters, like this: `scanf("%s",&item);`. Since `item` is an array, it will decay into the address of its first element, which is what you want. You don't want the address of the array, so the `&` is incorrect.